# Liberar porta local para o docker

Tags: docker

Quando eu dou um telnet de dentro do container na porta 3306 ele da mensagem de connection refused.

Ao rodar o comando abaixo tenho um erro dizendo que a porta está em uso

```
 docker run -td --name projeto -p 3306:3306 ambiente-dev-projeto-php56-newimage
```

erro:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint eLicitacao (b798a52246aca15563410c8967931be996eda3b4a8dffc3a261a75bda547bae1): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use.
```

parei o mysql da minha máquina e rodei o comando, ele funciona, porém, ao subir novamente o mysql, ele da erro

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

tentei adicionar essa porta no docker-compose e tive os mesmos problemas

Comment: Você está tentando acessar uma porta da sua máquina dentro do docker? Por que?

Comment: Preciso acessar o MySQL da minha máquina

Comment: Já tentou conectar diretamente pelo IP local da sua máquina? Tipo 192.168.1.42:3306

Comment: Minha configuração no projeto está assim, da connection refused

Comment: Fui testar, entrei no docker, consigo pingar a porta 80 e não consigo essa

Comment: Já deu uma lida no report de erro no `systemctl status mysql.service`?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente você tem outro serviço `MySql` utilizando a porta `:3306`, deve encerrar ou parar esse `container` primeiro.

Aconselho instalar o `Docker Portainer`para um melhor gerenciamento de imagens e containers, nesse [link](https://medium.com/@renato.groffe/docker-portainer-gerenciando-containers-a-partir-de-um-browser-87af6ce74be3) tem um tutorial.

Então, pare o compose `docker-compose down` e restarte com `docker-compose up`.

Outra opção é dentro do container executar os comandos:

```
sudo service mysqld stop  
sudo service apache2 stop
```

E em seguida executar no terminal do host `docker-compose up -d ...`.

Ou então, basta utilizar uma outra porta para seu `MySql`, como por exemplo a `:3307`, é o mais rápido e prático.